# How to get the Last Value from Cookie with 2 variables inside Using split() methode in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have cookie that consist of 2 variables. I want to get the value from the variable #2 (the last one) But I don´t know how to deal with that.

**From PHP**

I have set cookie like this :

```
 setcookie ('mysite'.$user_id,'user_id='. $user_id. '&msg_id='. $c_id, time() + $cookie_time);
```

What I'm trying to get is the **value** of **msg_id**

**In javascript**

```
var ca="mysite"+user_id;
    ca = new Array();
        ca = document.cookie.split(';');

        for (var w in ca)

        NmeVal  = new Array();
        NmeVal  = ca[w].split('=');
```

But how can I get just only the value of `msg_id` as I mentioned above?

**UPDATE**

I got it to work now by doing this:

```
var NmeVal  = new Array();

    NmeVal  = ca[w].split('=');

    var vl =unescape(NmeVal[1]);  

    var gala = vl.split('=');

    alert(gala[2]);
```

I get the only value I want::
it work in IE, FIrefox, Chrome

But why didn´t it work in **Safari** ?

**UPDATE # FINAL**
Finally I found the solution jquery.cookie.js
Only 3 lines work and the job is done !!!

Create - get - delete cookie like crazy and the plugin is not that big file like other packages.

And because of this plug in I start to use cookie like crazy now :)

Comment: What is the content/value of `document.cookie` before splitting it?

Comment: Could you add the output of `console.log(document.cookie)` to your question?

Comment: Here :

PHPSESSID=oleGInunYQIP7QSLpDUVR3, mysite=usr%3DChrome%26hash%3D594f803b380a41396ed63dca39503542

Comment: I'm not seeing msg_id in that cookie - only `usr` and `hash`: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fM4wn/1/).  Results: `{"PHPSESSID":"oleGInunYQIP7QSLpDUVR3"," mysite":"usr=Chrome&hash=594f803b380a41396ed63dca39503542"}`

Comment: Now what I have test above stop working again.
I think I will give up. Too complicated :S

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36672/discussion-between-dc5-and-poramat-fin)

Answer (score 0):

You are better of storing information in cookies this way:

```
setcookie("user_id", $user_id);
setcookie("msg_id", $c_id);
// ...
```

Javascript function for getting the cookie value by giving a name:

```
var user_id = getCookie("user_id");

function getCookie(name) {
    var result = ""; 
    var myCookie = " " + document.cookie + ";";
    var searchName = " " + name + "=";
    var startOfCookie = myCookie.indexOf(searchName); 

    var endOfCookie; 
    if (startOfCookie != -1) {
        startOfCookie += searchName.length; 
        endOfCookie = myCookie.indexOf(";", startOfCookie); 
        result = unescape(myCookie.substring(startOfCookie, endOfCookie)); 
    }
    return result; 
}
```

Comment: Hi KennyDs Thanks for the answer. I have my own reason to set cookie like that. Because this cookie will be used in many differences functions both in PHP and javascript.

But is that impossible to get the value that I want from my cookie ?

Answer (score 0):

When you are parsing a cookie, parse from the outside in.

One thing I found when parsing the cookie you posted was an additional space before 'mysite'. Using the console and logging the results of each step can help you find small issues like that.

- Split first by ','
- loop and split by '='
- unescape value to the right of the '='
- Then in your case, loop and split by '&'

This routine should work for you ([Fiddle][5]):

```
// Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim
if (!String.prototype.trim) {
    String.prototype.trim = function () {
        return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    };
}


function parseCookie(cookie) {
    var vals = cookie.split(',');
    var nameValue = {}, cur, mysite;

    for (var i = 0; i < vals.length; ++i) {
        cur = vals[i].split('=');
        nameValue[cur[0].trim()] = unescape(cur[1]);
    }

    mysite = nameValue.mysite.split('&');
    nameValue.mysite = {};
    for (i = 0; i < mysite.length; ++i) {
        cur = mysite[i].split('=');
        nameValue.mysite[cur[0].trim()] = cur[1];
    }

    return nameValue;
}

var cookie = "PHPSESSID=oleGInunYQIP7QSLpDUVR3, mysite=usr%3DChrome%26hash%3D594f803b380a41396ed63dca39503542";

console.log(JSON.stringify(parseCookie(cookie)));
```

Result:

```
{"PHPSESSID":"oleGInunYQIP7QSLpDUVR3","mysite":{"usr":"Chrome","hash":"594f803b380a41396ed63dca39503542"}}
```

You can retrieve any value you need by something like:

```
var usr = result.mysite.usr;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. First I have to say that this is a ajax function. I can not have another function inside. So what I did : I put the function parseCookie(cookie) out side my function. Then inside my function: var cookie="mysite"+user_id; cookie = document.cookie;  AFter that: I really don´t know how to send the cookie to function parseCookie(cookie). And How to get that value.

Because when I call function parseCookie(cookie) from inside my function, everything stop working.